# Does highest accuracy giving algorithm still give highest accuracy out of all after preprocessing data set?

Tags: machine-learning, regression, data-science, classification, logistic-regression

I have a dataset on which I need to apply binary classification to predict target value. I applied 5 algorithms on training set such as Logistic regression, Naive Bayes, KNN, SVM, Decision Trees. Out of which Binary Classification using Logistic Regression is giving me highest accuracy but the thing is I did not preprocess my dataset. Now should I again train my model using all five algorithms or Is it sure that Binary Classification using Logistic Regression will again give my highest accuracy after pre processing training dataset?

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it is not about programming as defined in the help center but about ML theory and/or methodology - please see the intro and NOTE in https://stackoverflow.com/tags/machine-learning/info

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No one can tell you if the results will be different after pre-processing, since we don't know what pre-processing you will be doing. But best practices are to pre-process that dataset uniformly so that all algorithms are being trained on the same data.